# Tor Browser won't load in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu, verification

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried to download Tor Browser from the Tor website and using the Tor Browser package from the Ubuntu software application. Each time I get a message titled Signature Verification Failed. The message is:

```
You might be under attack, or there might just be a networking problem. Click Start to try the download again.
```

I have tried many times, always getting the same result. I have wiped the hard drive and reloaded Ubuntu three times, and each time I got the same error. I have successfully installed Tor on my laptop which uses the same router and internet connection.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with `torbrowser-launcher`, the package that Ubuntu ships that gives errors like you describe. That software isn't maintained by the Tor Project, you might prefer downloading it directly from https://torproject.org/

Comment: Once you download and extract Tor Browser from the Tor Project website, if you could include the terminate output from `tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser --debug`. If required replace `en-US` with the appropriate country code for your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an outdated key.  [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/912336/913773) solution fixed the issue for me:

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu`